# Two listboxes with equal width in one container div

Tags: javascript, html, css, listbox

I try to create complex control in my online application. Control have two listboxes and two buttons between. Width of listboxes (listbox-target, listbox-source) must be equal. Width of control-buttons can be fixed. Height of all controls must be equal too. `HTML` and `JS` code below.

I try to make this with css, but can't. I wrote javascript to calculacte width and height of each element.

```
Width of listbox-target = listbox-source = ('fullwidth of attributeref-two-listboxes' - 'width of control-buttons') / 2.
```

It work good, but must be called everytime from resize event. Sometimes resize event is not fire and width of controls not change.

I think, best of all is make this with css only, but how?! Please, help!

```
function resizeAttributerefTwoListboxes() {
var is_ff = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1,
    is_ie = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('MSIE') > -1 || /Trident.*rv[ :]*(\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent);
$("div.attributeref-two-listboxes div").removeAttr("style");
$("div.attributeref-two-listboxes").each(function(){
    var that = $(this),
        target = that.find(".listbox-target"),
        source = that.find(".listbox-source"),
        control = that.find(".control-buttons");
    if (this.offsetWidth < 420) {
        control.find('a[method="add"] > i').addClass("fa-angle-up").removeClass("fa-angle-left");
        control.find('a[method="remove"] > i').addClass("fa-angle-down").removeClass("fa-angle-right");
        target.css({"width":"100%"});
        control.css({"width":"100%"});
        control.children().css({"display":"inline-block"});
        source.css({"width":"100%"});
    } else {    //horizontal alignment
        control.find('a[method="add"] > i').addClass("fa-angle-left").removeClass("fa-angle-up");
        control.find('a[method="remove"] > i').addClass("fa-angle-right").removeClass("fa-angle-down");
        var w = Math.ceil((this.offsetWidth - control[0].offsetWidth - (is_ff || is_ie ? 2 : 1))/2);
        target.css({"width":w+"px"});
        source.css({"width":w+"px"});
        control.children().css({"height":(target[0].offsetHeight-20)+"px"}); //20 - paddings from top and bottom (10+10)
        control.css({"height":target[0].offsetHeight+"px"});
    }
});
}

<div class="attributeref-two-listboxes">
<div class="listbox-target" style="width: 549px;">
    <select id="Objectint_chg_management_change_user" acode="chg_management_change_user" atype="8" astyle="3" aislist="0" class="form-control tooltipstered" multiple="multiple" style="max-width: 750px;" size="4" name="Objectint[chg_management_change_user][]"></select>
</div>
<div class="control-buttons" style="height: 90px;">
    <div style="height: 70px;">
        <a class="btn btn-primary option mover" target="Objectint_chg_management_change_user" source="Objectint_chg_management_change_user_select" method="add" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary option mover" target="Objectint_chg_management_change_user" source="Objectint_chg_management_change_user_select" method="remove" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="listbox-source" style="width: 549px;">
    <select id="Objectint_chg_management_change_user_select" acode="chg_management_change_user" atype="8" astyle="3" aislist="0" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="max-width: 750px;" size="4" name="[]">
        <option value="68">User 1</option>
        <option value="61">User 2</option>
        <option value="76">User 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[this is my control after right resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itxZs.png)

[this is my control after wrong resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIACD.png)

Comment: Short update! I forget write, that in small screen listboxes and control buttons must have vertical orientation. Listbox-target on top, then control buttons and listbox-source in bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex-box allow to avoid using JS in some cases like your.

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/852gin/2b64Ldw8/3/) 
.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .flex_container {
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
.arrays_v {display : none}
.arrays_h {display : inline}    
}
```

I suppose my my solution will be useful for you.

Comment: style="width: 549px;" - this style in div was added by javascript. I remove this style from listbox-target and listbox-source. Add style: .listbox-target, .listbox-source { width: 100%; } Looks good. Possible make this w/o flex?

Comment: I think it is possible w/o flex, however it would not so flexible and graceful.
Flex is common practice even Bootstrap 4 include it.

Comment: I try to use css with flex and have a trouble. I add -ms-flex: 1; -webkit-flex: 1; to listbox-target and listbox-source to correct display controls in IE11. But there are other problems.

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alxd/7jzja97r/) Normal display in FF only, Chrome display buttons in one row (no vertical orientation on big screens), IE display on big screen like a Chrome, but on small screen - trash. [display in big screen](http://alxd.it-dept.ru/download/flex-bug1.png) and [display in small screen](http://alxd.it-dept.ru/download/flex-bug2.png) @AlexeiZababurin, please help!

Comment: Dear Alexander, unfortunately I did couldn't grasp thicket of your classes and tags quickly. So please prepare your question JSFiddle little bit  more thoroughly so far as it is a base of fast and correct answer.

Comment: Dear @Alexei, link to JSFiddle and links to screenshots in my previous comment. I repeat it: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alxd/7jzja97r/),
[controls on big screen](http://alxd.it-dept.ru/download/flex-bug1.png),
[controls on small screen](http://alxd.it-dept.ru/download/flex-bug2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left` and `min-width`.

The `min-width` should be at least the widths of the elements. If the section can span the entire width of the page, using `960px` is not a bad idea because it displays well in most form factors (tablets, smartphones, PCs, occupies 1/2 of a 1080p display).

This way you can also avoid using `display: inline-block` which is not supported in older browsers (though that window keeps sliding forward so this isn't much of a problem these days except for enterprise web apps,etc.).

```css
.attributeref-two-listboxes {
  min-width: 960px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
.chooser
{
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  }
.buttons
{
  float: left;  
  }
.buttons input
{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(34,131,203);
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: block;
  margin: 13px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="attributeref-two-listboxes">
<select multiple size=4 class='chooser'>
  <option>Uno</option>
  <option>Dos</option>
  <option>Tres</option>
</select>
<div class='buttons'>
  <input type='button' value='&lt;' />
  <input type='button' value='&gt;' />
</div>
<select multiple size=4 class='chooser'>
  <option>Uno</option>
  <option>Dos</option>
  <option>Tres</option>
</select>
</div>
```